# Getting dynamically added inputs from request

Tags: django, http, post, request

I have a form that has arbitrary many input fields:

```
<form method='post' action='/SaveIt/'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div id="id0">
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name0">
        <label>Age:</label> <input type="text" name="age0">
        <span class="add">Add fields</span>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
       <button type="submit">Save all</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
var c = 1;
$(".add").click(function() {
    $("#id0").clone(true).attr('id', 'id' + c).attr('name', 'name' + c)
    .insertBefore("form > div:last-child");
    c++;
    return false;
});

</script>
```

This adds fields nicely and they have correct ids and names.
However the request I get in the view doesn't seem to have them:

```
def SaveIt(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.POST)
```

returns only age0 and name0. Is there a way to get a hold of these dynamically created inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jquery method/logic is wrong. `$("#id0").clone(true)` will make clone of `div` whose id is `id0` and when you do `.attr('id', 'id' + c)` you are actually setting the id and name on div rather than on input which is inside it. You need this:

```
var c = 1;
$(".add").click(function() {
    var prev = c -1;
    $("#id" + prev).clone(true).attr('id', 'id' + c)
    .insertBefore("form > div:last-child");
    $("#id"+c+" > input[name=name"+prev+"]").attr('name', 'name' + c);
    $("#id"+c+" > input[name=age"+prev+"]").attr('name', 'age' + c);
    c++;
    return false;
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LE4US/).